# I can't get a background image size to change

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to HTML and CSS.
I'm using a book called *The Missing Manual, CSS3* and I'm stuck on changing the size of an image that I want to use as a background. To help isolate the problem, I made up simple HTML and CSS files, but I still can't get the `background-size` property to actually do anything. The image shows OK and I can change the repeat, but no matter what I put for background-size (% or px) the size of the image never changes (bigger or smaller). I've tried also changing the image to a PNG, but still a no-go. The `sprial.jpg` image size is 292x288 px - so 'small' that I may not use it in the end.

I'm using Notepad++ to write the code and Chrome to view it.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/08/21/39/spiral-2730290__180.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size;
  50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p> Hello
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: background-size: 50% 50%;

it should be : not ;

Comment: Well, I sort of knew I'd be embarrassed by the solution and I certainly am. Thanks for this. I'll certainly be using this forum in future, hopefully with less lame questions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo on

```
backgroud-size: 50% 50%;
```

This should work fine.

NOTE:
You should add some plugin that helps you with this kind of simples syntax error. For instance this one: [Css Explorer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cssexplorerplug/files/2.0.3/CSSEXplorer.2.0.3.BIN.zip/download)

Comment: Thanks for the solution and also the tip - Notepad++ doesn't flag this up. I'll have a look at the link you've provided.

Comment: Update - I've just had a look and it seems this plugin is for XP only. I have Windows 10. Am I right?

Comment: actually i don't use nor Notepad++ nor Windows since long time, try to google something, or use Atom.io, way better and better supported editor IMHO.

Comment: I would do but I can't see how to do that. Apparently I can 'accept' an answer but can't see a way to do that. Maybe my low 'reputation'?

Comment: @JohnB47 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the semicolon, you write `background-size;` instead of `background-size:`.

Comment: Thanks to you also. Well spotted. What an idiot I am.

Comment: We've all been there :P